# Вебхуки МойСклад

Tags: мойсклад-api, moysklad-json-api

Как можно проверить работу вебхуков?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте воспользоваться сервисом https://webhook.site/ . Сервис сгенерирует временный url, на который можно привязать вебхук, по нему же отследить.

Инструкцию по работе с вебхуками МоегоСклада можно посмотреть здесь https://moysklad.github.io/workbook/api/remap/1.1/ru/webhooks.html